# Как узнать имя бота по api ключам?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Заказчик мне дал 2 апи ключа: api,secret keys,сказал для ознакомления.До этого я взаимодействовал с ботами только через bot father.Если кто знает подскажите как получить имя бота по api бота.

Comment: `print(bot.get_me())` для `pytelegrambotapi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод [`getMe`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getme). Пример с использованием библиотеки [`westacks/telebot`](https://github.com/westacks/telebot):

```php
// index.php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use WeStacks\TeleBot\TeleBot;

$bot = new TeleBot('123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11'); // API-токен бота здесь
$bot_user = $bot->getMe();

var_dump($bot_user);
```

Выполнив файл в консоли - `php index.php`, получаем вывод информации о боте:

```
object(WeStacks\TeleBot\Objects\User)#31 (7) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1234567890)
  ["is_bot"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["first_name"]=>
  string(23) "Example Bot"
  ["username"]=>
  string(23) "example_bot"
  // ...
}
```